# How can I easily get (or generate) images of single notes of written music?

Tags: notation

Here is an image of what I am hoping to retrieve (or generate) from somewhere:

[image: Note a]

I need something similar for different pitches. I could make screenshots in Musescore (or some other musical editor), but that seems like a lot of work. Surely there has to be better way.

Comment: If you google "Note A", "Note B", "Note Db" etc, you can get these pictures

Comment: How many pitches do you need? This looks like something that can be done in 1 minute per pitch, max. Spend hours coding or let other people spend the hours, in order to save 30 minutes of work? ;)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the [Note image generator](https://notes.bretpimentel.com/) on the site of woodwind doubler and blogger Bret Pimentel is what you are looking for. It's a web page that generates graphics of single notes in any desired size. It only generates whole notes, but maybe that's good enough for you.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you can use my extension [abcjs-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alensiljak.abcjs-vscode). It could hardly be any simpler. All you need to do is type the letter "A" to get the image you want:

[image: screenshot]

You can also use Paul's [online editor](https://editor.drawthedots.com/). Both options are using his excellent abcjs library. You might want to get familiar with ABC music notation for quick jots like this, or even for more-involved pieces.
Cheers

Edit: Apologies. To be technically correct, you might want to add the bar line "|" after the note A. ;)

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2):

If you’re on Windows 10 you can use the snipping tool (ctrl-shift-s) to grab an image of just a section of your screen, so using that it would be quick to create them in MuseScore.

Comment: This is what I do usually (which can be done on older versions of Windows and Mac as well), it's not limited to Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to imagine an easier method than creating it in MuseScore and clipping out a screenshot.   Maybe there's a comprehensive set of ready-made ones out there in Google-land, but I can't see it.

Comment: There sure is. By the time one goes through the New Sheet wizard in MuseScore, it is possible to jot down a whole complex line or half a lead sheet with abc. :D

Answer (score 1):

You might try googling "music notation flashcards" to see if what's available would suit your needs.